# Unity Facebook sdk not working in iphone device

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-login

I am working on login with facebook in unity. it's working proper in editor but not working in iphone device.

My error is :

Could not load file or assembly ‘Facebook.Unity.IOS’ or one of its dependancy

Facebook object is not yet loaded. Did you call FB.Init()?

Comment: Well, have you called `FB.Init()` in your code?

Comment: Yes, it's working fine in Editor. @Stijn

Here is my Code : Facebook.Unity.FB.Init (SetInit, OnHideUnity);

Comment: FileNotFoundException:Could not load file or assembly ‘Facebook.Unity.IOS’ or one of its dependencies. The system can not find the file specified.